# Why does this beginner python program stop midway?

Tags: python

This is my first day learning python from a book called "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python".

On the "your first program" section the program is this

```
# This program says hello and asks for my name.
print('Hello world!')
print('What is your name?')  # ask for their name
myName = input("Mizu")
print('It is good to meet you, ' + myName)
print('The length of your name is:')
print(len(myName))
print('What is your age?')  # ask for their age
myAge = input('20')
print('You will be ' + str(int(myAge) + 1) + ' in a year.')
```

but the program only runs

```
Hello world!
What is your name?
Mizu
```

but if i replace the input() functions with just values like myName = 'Mizu' , it prints the rest of the lines just fine.

What am i doing wrong here?

i used the default python editor and pycharm and both show no errors or anything.

Comment: Input waits for you to insert values  in the prompt

Comment: Because you are asking for input. So, you must type something in your command prompt or terminal. Then it'll work.

Comment: And BTW the argument to `input()` is the prompt text, not a default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, the book says

```
myName = input()
```

so that's what you put in your programme, not

```
myName = input("Mizu")
```

and then, likes others have written, when the programme gets there you type in your name.

CAUTION this is correct for python 3. Check your version. If you are using python 2, replace "input" with "raw_input()"

```
myName = raw_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` means that it's waiting for you to write something.
Type something and press"Enter"

It isn't stopped.

Answer (score 0):

you need to type some thing after the third line like
$Mizu"Mizu".
The Mizu shown on the run is just a reminder message to let know which input are you giving value.

Answer (score 0):

The programme is not stopped. It is waiting for your input.
In the input function you have to give some valut at the run time.
myName = input("Mizu"). In this line you have entered your question. You have to give answer at run time
myName = input("what is your name")